# Starting Off Low-Level Port Access

Tags: arduino-uno, debugging, arduino-uno-smd

I'm trying to teach myself some low[er] level code, but I just can't get it to work. I've tried OR-ing stuff in, AND-ing stuff in, and just straight up defining stuff, but it's not blinking! What am I doing wrong here?

I am using an Arduino UNO R3 DIP for this. I am just using the on-board LED, (on pin13/PORTB_5)

Current code:

```
#define STATE B00001000
#define ZERO B00000000
void setup() {
    DDRB = STATE;
    }

void loop(){
    PORTB |= STATE;
    delay(500);
    PORTB &= ZERO;
    delay(500);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would probably help if you were using the right pin.  In the pins_arduino.h file for the Uno is this diagram:

```
//                  +-\/-+
//            PC6  1|    |28  PC5 (AI 5)
//      (D 0) PD0  2|    |27  PC4 (AI 4)
//      (D 1) PD1  3|    |26  PC3 (AI 3)
//      (D 2) PD2  4|    |25  PC2 (AI 2)
// PWM+ (D 3) PD3  5|    |24  PC1 (AI 1)
//      (D 4) PD4  6|    |23  PC0 (AI 0)
//            VCC  7|    |22  GND
//            GND  8|    |21  AREF
//            PB6  9|    |20  AVCC
//            PB7 10|    |19  PB5 (D 13)
// PWM+ (D 5) PD5 11|    |18  PB4 (D 12)
// PWM+ (D 6) PD6 12|    |17  PB3 (D 11) PWM
//      (D 7) PD7 13|    |16  PB2 (D 10) PWM
//      (D 8) PB0 14|    |15  PB1 (D 9) PWM
//                  +----+
```

That shows that pin D 13 is PB5 which would be a binary value of `0b00100000` not `0b00001000` as you have, which would be PB3, or pin D11.

The only way I can come up with `0b00001000` is if I count from the left (wrong) and start at 1 (wrong) rather than count from the right (right) and start at 0 (right).

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I did... I'm used to the other bit order, so that's what screwed me up. And also counting from 1... Oops. But thanks!

Comment: The other bit order? There is only one bit order. All numbers count from the right. After all, 5 + 7 isn't 21, it's 12. The same applies to all bases - base 2 (binary), base 16 (hexadecimal), base 60 (sexagecimal)...

Comment: I was thinking of MSBF vs LSBF haha

Comment: That only makes any sense in the scope of serial communication.

Comment: Oh, by the way - your logical operators are pretty pointless.  The OR is OK since it just turns on one pin, but the AND is bad, since it turns off ALL pins.  You should be ANDing with `0b11011111` to maintain the state of all the other pins.  That would be equivalent to `PORTB &= ~STATE`.